# How to open a new terminal and run two linux commands?

Tags: bash, shell

I have create a .sh script, with option to open terminal and that same terminal run 2 commands.
I know to open a new window or tab and run a command but when I put && I receive  error like this by using this command:

Commands:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -- "ls && clear"
```

Error:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process “ls && clear” (No such file or directory)
```

My OS is Linux(Ubuntu)

Comment: What's the point of `ls && clear` which only runs `clear` if `ls` fails. How could `ls` fail? Why clear the screen of your results as soon as you generate them?

Answer (score 3):

`gnome-terminal` is expecting a command name. It looks for a command literally called `ls && clear` but can't find it. You need to run it in a shell:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -c "ls && clear"
```

Comment: `-x`  is deprecated in favor of  `--`.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu The Ubuntu manpage doesn't mention `--`. (I just added a link to the manpage for 18.04.) I'm not at my machine ATM so can't check, but `-x` still works, right?

Comment: Yes, it works. But it show the following message:
```
# Option “-x” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

Comment: On gnome-terminal version `GNOME Terminal 3.28.2 using VTE 0.52.2 +GNUTLS -PCRE2`

Comment: @Gonzalo Huh, I couldn't find any documentation about the deprecation, but a lot of other questions on SE that mention it. So I updated the answer.