# Go program doesn't open a window on linux

Tags: ubuntu

I simplified my problem to very simple program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Test")

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}
```

I compile this simply by using `go build main.go`. Nothing special.

On both windows and mac when I run the program it opens a window which stays open for a few seconds and then closes as expected.

On ubuntu however no window opens. The program still does what it's supposed to (like if I change it to create a file or something it happens) but why does the window not open? I need to be able to give some info to the user and I don't want to force them to start it from terminal.

Comment: `it opens a window which stays open for a few seconds and then closes as expected` that's not what happens at all. Running a console application doesn't open a new window either on Mac or Windows. It's only *your IDE* that opens a new *terminal* to run your application and show its output. If you built and run your code from the same terminal there wouldn't be a new window. The current terminal would be used. If you started your program from another one no terminal would be opened

Comment: You misunderstand, I'm not using IDE to run it. I compile it and then double click the compiled file. Both mac and windows open a window.

Comment: And if you open a terminal, they don't. You misunderstood what you saw. The *UI shell* in Windows and Mac open a *terminal* to show the output of the program. If you started the program from any other application there wouldn't be any additional window. If you schedule the execution, there won't be any window

Comment: I didn't misunderstand anything, I know all that... but how do I fix it? How do I make it open a window on linux?

Comment: Or at least how do I detect that the program is running in a way that there is now window for the output?

Comment: If you do, you understand it's the desktop manager that decides to open a new terminal before running your app. If your desktop manager doesn't do so (GNOME doesn't) you'll have to create a script that starts a terminal and executes your app. There are duplicate questions already like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448239/how-to-open-a-new-terminal-and-run-two-linux-commands) and [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974756/how-can-i-open-a-extra-console-and-run-a-program-in-it-with-one-command)  in AskUbuntu.

Comment: GNOME itself [doesn't like starting applications by double clicking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379725/launch-script-with-double-click-dont-work). The answer to that question shows how to specify `gnome-terminal` as a launcher

Comment: I don't see how any of that helps. One of the questions mentions desktop files but those seem to be located elsewhere than the app itself so the users won't have it. Adding a script that would start a terminal and execute my app within it sounds good but only if it doesn't care what terminal is actually used. For all I know people can run this on other systems without gnome.

Comment: For instance I know people will want to run my app on steam deck too.

Comment: I suggest you read [Windows Command-Line: Backgrounder](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-backgrounder/) and possibly [Windows Command-Line: The Evolution of the Windows Command-Line](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-the-evolution-of-the-windows-command-line/) too

Comment: How is that even relevant? That's clearly about windows.

Comment: And you're trying to emulate how Windows behaves. Don't you want to see what you're really asking? Or why your assumption is wrong?

Comment: Since it doesn't lead to a solution... no I don't care.

Comment: The problem is your incorrect assumptions, not Linux. As long as you refuse to let go of them, no solution will work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a new terminal and run two linux commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448239/how-to-open-a-new-terminal-and-run-two-linux-commands)

Comment: There isn't really anything to fix on my side. It simply means the problem doesn't have a solution other than change my program into one with actual GUI.

Comment: This is an OS question and not a Go question - nothing about this behavior is related to the language the program was written in, this is just how your OS handles executing a binary with no GUI.

Answer (score 3):

### A bit of theory

The reason is as follows (I'm not well-versed in Mac OS): on Windows, any executable image file has a special field in its metadata block which tells which "subsystem" the compiled program belongs, which are "GUI" and "console".
If the subsystem is "GUI" the program is started with its [standard I/O streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) closed, and it's supposed the program will call into Win32 API to actually display GUI in its own window or a set of windows.
If the subsystem is "console", *and* Windows detects the program was not started in an exising console session–say, the user hit <kbd>Win-R</kbd> and typed the program's name here–as opposing to doing that at what Windows calls "a console prompt",–Windows creates a new console *window,* shows it on screen and makes that program run with its standard I/O streams connected to that console.

Conversely, GUI environments of Unix heritage, included various OSes based on Linux, implement different approach: programs do not belong to GUI/non-GUI "subsystems", and are always started with their standard I/O streams connected somewhere (unless overridden at startup)–typically to those of the parent process.

Another thing to note is that Linux-based systems do not have any notion of "the standard" "console window". What they have (most of the time, though, technically, not oblidged) is one or more GUI terminal emulators: programs, which show a console-like interface in a GUI window. Say, when you open Terminal in Ubuntu, that Terminal is actually a terminal emulator. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21858818/720999) I tried to explain this concept to someone with further pointers.

### What to do

On a Linux-based system, you have no other option except running a terminal emulator window explicitly. Most of them support the `-e` command-line option (sort of standardized by the venerable `xterm`, I think) to pass the command to execute (instead of the shell configured for the user), and Debian and Debian-derived systems, Ubuntu included, usually ship a symbolic link named `x-terminal-emulator` which points at what is the default GUI terminal emulator in your particular system.

Having said that, I would still reconsider your approach: folks familiar with Unix-like systems *do not expect* terminal windows to pop up¹. You might still have legitimate reasons to do what you're after, sure, I just urge you to look at that issues from a different perspective. After all, there are different approaches to notify the user on Linux-based GUI systems: from old-school running of `xmessage` to using `libnotify` or directly asking the active notification server over d-bus to show the user a message–see [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_notifications) for more details. Or using [Zenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity), or [something like it](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ncruces/zenity).
The chief problem with your prospective approach is that a Unix-like system typically runs fine w/o any GUIs. More so, on your Ubuntu system, you may easily drop into a Linux's [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) to see a "non-GUI command-line environment". If I were to run your program there, and it would try to spawn a terminal emulator (which would likely fail to start), I'd be disappointed.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23743217/720999) for a problem reverse to yours ;-)

---

¹ If you'll squint at it for some time, you'll notice that there's no single good solution: when I run a program at the <kbd>Win-R</kbd> prompt only to see a console window pop up and immediately close, it's as annoying as having it the other way.
Contemporary Linux-based desktop environments–such as GNOME solve that by making GUI apps only available in menus and the search if they install a special `.desktop` file. Windows has basically the same thing for ages: you usually cannot easily execute an installed GUI program except by finding it in the Start menu or via search.
By the same logic, if something is available via `$PATH` or `%PATH%`, it's *supposed* to be run from an existing console window/terminal emulator.

Comment: When I double click a program and GNOME runs it, where are the IO streams actually connected? And is there some way for the program to detect the case where it isn't connected to a terminal?

Comment: @kostix since Windows 10 and the new Console infrastructure, Windows has no default console either.

Comment: @enumag, «where are the IO streams actually connected?»–to the streams of the program which actually performed `fork(2)`+`exec(2)` to run yours. And that one interited its std streams from its parent, and so on. These days the streams usually end up being intercepted by `systemd` which started your "session", and logged (run `journalctl -e` to see them).

Comment: @enumag to a pseudoterminal that doesn't have to be connected to an actual terminal application. That's explained in the [Windows Command-Line: Introducing the Windows Pseudo Console (ConPTY)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/) article I posted in the comments.

Comment: In fact, even the difference between Windows and Linux is described in the [Launching the Console - Or Not](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-inside-the-windows-console/#launching-the-console--or-not) section of `Inside The Windows Console`. You're looking for OS/Desktop manager features in the wrong place

Comment: @enumag, «is there some way for the program to detect the case where it isn't connected to a terminal?»–[yes](https://github.com/mattn/go-isatty). Basically, most of interpreters of popular programming languages such as Python, Tcl, and Unix shells such as `bash` and `zsh` use this to either go interactive or not. But then again I would say that your approach may be flawed from the outset, and I recommend to put more thought and research into expected behavior.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, that's an interesting piece, thanks.

Comment: «run `journalctl -e` to see them»–sorry, that should have been `journalctl --user -e`.